# Sed's regex to eliminate a very specific string

Tags: sed, ksh

**Disclaimer:**

I have found several examples in this site that address questions/problems similar to mine, though I was unfortunately not able to figure out the modifications that would need to be introduced to fit my needs.

**The "Problem":**

I have a list of servers (VMs) that have it's UUID embedded as part of the name. I need to get rid of that in order to obtain the "pure/clean" server name. Now, the problem is precisely that: **I need to get rid of the UUID (which has a very specific and constant format, more details on this below) and ONLY that, nothing else.**

The UUID - as you might already know or have noticed - has a specific and constant format which consists of the following parts:

1. It starts with a dash (`-`).
2. Which is followed by a subset of 8 alphanumeric characters (letters are always lowercase).
3. Which is followed by a dash (`-`).
4. Which is followed by a subset of 4 alphanumeric characters (letters are always lowercase).
5. Which is followed by a dash (`-`).
6. Which is followed by a subset of 4 alphanumeric characters (letters are always lowercase).
7. Which is followed by a dash (`-`).
8. Which is followed by a subset of 4 alphanumeric characters (letters are always lowercase).
9. Which is followed by a dash (`-`).
10. Which is followed by a subset of 12 alphanumeric characters (letters are always lowercase).

**Samples of results achieved using "my" """"code"""":**

In this case the result is the expected one:

```
echo PRODSERVER0022-872151c8-1a75-43fb-9b63-e77652931d3f | sed 's/-[a-z0-9]*//g'
PRODSERVER0022
```

In this case the result is the expected one too:

```
echo PRODSERVER0022-872151c8-1a75-43fb-9b63-e77652931d3f_OLD | sed 's/-[a-z0-9]*//g'
PRODSERVER0022_OLD
```

Expected result: `PRODSERVER0022-OLD`

```
echo PRODSERVER0022-872151c8-1a75-43fb-9b63-e77652931d3f-OLD | sed 's/-[a-z0-9]*//g'
PRODSERVER0022
```

Expected result: `PRODSERVER00-22`

```
echo PRODSERVER00-22-872151c8-1a75-43fb-9b63-e77652931d3f-old | sed 's/-[a-z0-9]*//g'
PRODSERVER00
```

I know that, within the *sed* universe, a `.` means "any character", while a `*` means "any number of the preceding character". However, what I would need in this case, as I see it at least, is a way to tell *sed* to do the replacement only if this specific sequence is present (8 alphanumeric characters [any, but specifically 8, not more, not less]; followed by a dash, then followed by 4 alphanumeric characters [any, but specifically 4, not more, not less], etc..). **So, the question would be: Is there a regex construction (or a combination [through piping I guess] of several of them, if it has to be the case) that can achieve the expected results in this case?**

**Note** that: Even though servers may have additional dashes (`-`) as part of their names, the resulting sub-strings will never consist of 8 characters, neither of 4. They might, however, end up having 12 characters, which, even though would initially match up with the last sub-string in the UUID, it will not be at the end of the string, so we have that to discriminate between these two 12-chars substrings (and also it will not be a problem if there is indeed a regex combination that can get rid of the UUID as a whole).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to match the UUID.

```
-[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}
```

Embed it in the `sed` command line in the usual way.  As Benjamin W. has said, we need to use extended regular expressiongs.

```
sed -E 's/-[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}//g'
```

Comment: You are using extended regular expressions, but sed uses basic regular expressions, unless you use the `-E` (or `-r`, in some places) flag.

Comment: Tripp, Benjamin:Thank you both for your prompt replies. This worked like a charm in my Linux terminal, however, (my bad, I completely forgot to mention it), I am using KSH (AIX) sed, and therefore the -E flag is not available. Can this be achieved with KSH sed? Thanks again for your support!